# Minimax in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe, minimax, minmax

As a practice project I made a Tic-Tac-Toe game on JSFiddle (because there aren't enough already, right?) and I progressed into adding an unbeatable AI. For the most part it works, but there are some combinations (e.g. setting X into fields 5, 9, 3 or into fields 3, 7, 9) that lead to the computer not calculating the optimal move properly.

The project on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jd8x0vjz/

And the relevant function starting at line 63:

```
function evaluateMove(move, player, depth) {
var gameStatus = evaluateGameStatus(move); //get status of current board
if (gameStatus < 2 && player)
    return -1; //if human won, return -1
if (gameStatus < 2 && !player)
    return 1; //if human lost, return 1

var returnValue = 0 //value to be returned later

for (var z = 0; z < 3; z++) { //loop for row
    for (var s = 0; s < 3; s++) { //loop for column
        if (move[z][s]) //if current slot has an x or o,
            continue; //skip it     
        var nextMove = cloneGameStatus(move); //create temporary array with base of current grid
        nextMove[z][s] = !player ? "x" : "o"; //assign first free field  the appropriate symbol
        var value = evaluateMove(nextMove, !player, depth+1);   //recursion but with switched player, to add the correct icon afterwards
        if ((value > returnValue) && player)
            returnValue = value;            
        if ((value < returnValue) && !player)
            returnValue = value;                
    }
}
return returnValue; //return value of current simulation
}
```

I think the last two if-clauses are causing these problems, since the computer does calculate the proper values (as observable in the debugger), but they're sometimes overwritten, but I am not sure if this really is the root of the problem. Any help or tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: Problem solved! Look for my answer below in case it is not the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the default value of returnValue being wrong definitely sent me down the right path; it didn't make everything magically work (would've been too nice if it did), but it did give me the right nudge. Since we don't want to return any value if nothing is calculated, I adjusted the evaluateMove function as following:

```
function evaluateMove(move, player, depth) {
var gameStatus = evaluateGameStatus(move); //get status of current board
if (gameStatus != 2)
    return gameStatus; //if the game is not running anymore, return result

var returnValue; //value to be returned later

for (var z = 0; z < 3; z++) { //loop for row
    for (var s = 0; s < 3; s++) { //loop for column
        if (move[z][s]) //if current slot has an x or o,
            continue; //skip it     
        var nextMove = cloneGameStatus(move); //create temporary array with base of current grid
        nextMove[z][s] = !player ? "x" : "o"; //assign first free field  the appropriate symbol
        var value = evaluateMove(nextMove, !player, depth+1);   //recursion but with switched player, to add the correct icon afterwards
        if ((value > returnValue || returnValue == null) && player)
            returnValue = value;            
        if ((value < returnValue || returnValue == null) && !player)
            returnValue = value;                
    }
}
return returnValue; //return value of current simulation
}
```

Now the default is null and as such should not throw the calculations off. What it did throw off however was the first block of checks, so I adjusted it to simply return the current status should the game have ended, instead of doing any elaborate checks. However *that* threw off the results because I'm using inversed default values in the two methods, so I had to adjust evaluateGameStatus too. Now if the human won it returns -1 instead of 1, and if the computer won it returns 1 instead of -1:

```
function evaluateGameStatus(gameStatus) { //a clusterfuck of winning combinations
if(
X Checks
)
return -1; //there's a successful combination of x's

else if(
O Checks
)
return 1; //there's a successful combination of o's

else {
for (var z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
    for (var s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
        if (!gameStatus[z][s])
            return 2; //if there is an empty field neither has won, continue playing
        }
    }

return 0; //there's no successful combination and max moves have been reached. it's a draw
}
}
```

I had to do the same adjustmends for the checkGameEnd function, obviously.
You'll notice that I changed the check for draws too. That is because, for some reason, the old check for count == maxMoves did not work anymore, so I changed to a loop which simply checks whether there is any empty field at all, and to return 2 if there is, and 0 if there is not (it returns 0 here because at this point it has run through all the checks: X hasn't won, O hasn't won, and there are no open slots left, so the game must be a draw).

Working project can now be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/h5zwzkm7/

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure this is the source of the problem but there is most definitely a bug in your code that will produce strange results. The line:

```
var returnValue = 0 //value to be returned later
```

is incorrect. Aside from the fact that you are missing a semi-colon, the proper code should be:

```
var returnValue = -1;
if(!player){
  returnValue = 1;
}
```

You want the default value for the maximum player to be negative so that he takes the best move, and for the minimizing player positive so he takes the worst move. The way you did it, if the maximizing player was faced only with options that valued -1, since -1 is less than 0, and returnValue was initialized to 0, 0 would be returned although the correct value to be returned is -1.